# Erro SQL em conexao fullcalendar

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

O meu código está retornando falso, já debuguei mas não acho o erro
ele retorna "Houve algum problema.."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Miminium Admin Template v.1">
    <meta name="author" content="Isna Nur Azis">
    <meta name="keyword" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Miminium</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/font-awesome.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/simple-line-icons.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/animate.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/plugins/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
    <link href="asset/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="asset/img/logomi.png">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    <script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>

    <script src='fullcalendar/lang/pt-br.js'></script>

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {   

            //CARREGA CALENDÁRIO E EVENTOS DO BANCO
            $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: '2017-10-12',
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, 
                events: 'eventos.php',           
                eventColor: '#dd6777'
            }); 

            //CADASTRA NOVO EVENTO
            $('#novo_evento').submit(function(){
                //serialize() junta todos os dados do form e deixa pronto pra ser enviado pelo ajax
                var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "cadastrar_evento.php",
                    data: dados,
                    success: function(data)
                    {   
                        if(data == "1"){
                            alert("Cadastrado com sucesso! ");
                            //atualiza a página!
                            location.reload();
                        }else{
                            alert("Houve algum problema.. ");
                        }
                    }
                });                
                return false;
            }); 
       }); 

    </script>

    <style>
        #calendario{
            position: relative;
            width: 70%;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }        
    </style>
  </head>
 <body id="mimin" class="dashboard">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default header navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="col-md-12 nav-wrapper">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="width:100%;">
              <div class="opener-left-menu is-open">
                <span class="top"></span>
                <span class="middle"></span>
                <span class="bottom"></span>
              </div>
                <a href="perfil.php" class="navbar-brand"> 
                 <b>Economic life</b>
                </a>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav search-nav">
                <li>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right user-nav">
                <li class="user-name"><span><?php echo $_SESSION['nome_usu']; ?></span></li>
                  <li class="dropdown avatar-dropdown">
                   <img src="asset/img/avatar.jpg" class="img-circle avatar" alt="user name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"/>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu user-dropdown">
                     <li><a href="perfil.php"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Meu perfil</a></li>
                     <li><a href="calendar.html"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> Meu calendario</a></li>
                     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                     <li class="more">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php"><span class="fa fa-power-off "></span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      <!-- end: Header -->
      <div class="container-fluid mimin-wrapper">
          <!-- start:Left Menu -->
            <div id="left-menu" style="position: absolute; float: left;">
              <div class="sub-left-menu scroll">
                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <li><div class="left-bg"></div></li>
                    <li class="time">
                      <h1 class="animated fadeInLeft">21:00</h1>
                      <p class="animated fadeInRight">o</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active ripple">
                      <a href="perfil.php" class="tree-toggle nav-header"><span class="fa-home fa"></span> Perfil 
                        <span class="fa-angle-right fa right-arrow text-right"></span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="ripple"><a class="tree-toggle nav-header"><span class="fa fa-table"></span> Tables  <span class="fa-angle-right fa right-arrow text-right"></span> </a>
                      <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                        <li><a href="handsontable.html">handsontable</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          <!-- end: Left Menu -->
          <!-- start: content -->
            <div id="content">
                <div class="panel">

                            <div id='calendario'>
                                <br/>
                                <form id="novo_evento" action="" method="post">
                                    Nome do Evento: <input type="text" name="nome" required/><br/><br/>            
                                    Data do Evento: <input type="date" name="data" required/><br/><br/>            
                                    <button type="submit"> Cadastrar novo evento </button>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Darlei, infelizmente o var_dump não esta sendo reconhecido, mas pelo visto ele não entra nem no ajax

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

tente dar um `console.log(data)` e certifique que você está com o console do navegador aberto (basta dar f12 na página e aba Console). 
Pois pode ser que o data esteja vazio, ou não está vindo do backend.

Outra verificação seria validar se está tudo ok com os dados que estão sendo enviados, dando um console.log no var dados (var dados = jQuery(this).serialize()).